# RobotFramework 'ASCII' codec can't decode byte 0xd7 in position 1: Ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, robotframework, decode, robotframework-ide

I use Robot Framework with ride to do python-auto-test, but I got this problem in Robot Framework console:

```
"FAILED D:\eclipse\oppoAutoTest\AutoTest\../../PyAutoTest/src/testTcardCopy.py 
FAILED D:\eclipse\oppoAutoTest\AutoTest\commonUserKeyWords\../../../PyAutoTest/src/testMkDir.py
FAILED ../../PyAutoTest/basic/testSwipeScreen.py 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd7 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)"
```

Can you help me ?

This is my Robot Framework code:

```
*** Settings ***
Library           
    ../../eclipse_workplace_java/PyAutoTest/src/testTcardCopy.py
Resource          commonUserKeyWords/BASIC.tsv
Resource          commonUserKeyWords/CAMERA.tsv

*** Test Cases ***
bspTcardTest
${test_v_file_dir_path}    set Variable    /storage/sdcard0/tmp
${test_v_file_dir_ifexitd_result}    ${test_v_file_dir_if_success}    
${test_v_file_dir_stdout}    ${test_v_file_dir_stdout_mount}    判断文件或文件 
   夹是否存在    ${test_v_file_dir_path}
log    ${test_v_file_dir_ifexitd_result}
log    ${test_v_file_dir_if_success}
log    ${test_v_file_dir_stdout}
log    ${test_v_file_dir_stdout_mount}
Should_Be_True    '${test_v_file_dir_if_success}'=='True'
```

My python code also has utf-8:

```
# coding=utf-8
```

Comment: I can't say much about this problem, except that the code of PyAutoTest/basic/testSwipeScreen.py is not using character encoding and considering it is an ASCII char. You could inspect the code and modify to use the encoding of your system. Please open a command window and show us the result of `chcp`. You can also enter the command to output your test file and see if the characters are correctly shown, with `type the_path_filename`. You can repeat the command after doing this other: `chcp 65001`.

Comment: i set system coding = utf-8 and set my python project to pythonpath and i solve this problem